# django admin when field is autocomplete it overrides ModelForm filter

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm having issue with Django admin. I want one of my foreign key fields to be searchable and I achieved that making it autocomplete.

```py
class CollectionAdmin(VersionAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CollectionForm
    autocomplete_fields = ["task"]
```

I also filter that foreign key in ModelForm.

```py
class CollectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Collection
        fields = "__all__"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.fields.get("task"):
            self.fields["task"].queryset = self.fields["task"].queryset.filter(
                status=TaskStatus.ASSIGNED
            )
```

When task is **not** autocomplete field in Collection my filter **works as expected**.
However, when task is **autocomplete** field in Collection, filter **does not work**.
Instead of my filter in form, task admin `get_queryset` method is called which is not what I want.

`TaskAdmin.get_queryset` method just filters by user, however I want more filter as you see above, for `TaskStatus` as well.

```py
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    if request.user.groups.filter(name=settings.COPYWRITER_GROUP).exists():
        return qs.filter(assigned_to=request.user)
    return qs
```

Repeating, form init filter works if field is not autocomplete.

I tried removing task from autocomplete of `Collection` and it worked.

I want my form filter not to be overridden if the field is autocomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.
When you make field autocomplete, it directly triggers get_queryset method of that model admin.
So, in my case, TaskAdmin get_queryset is called each time when I try to select value from dropdown.
That is why, form filter became useless, we can actually totally remove that filter.
Workaround is to conditionally filtering objects in TaskAdmin get_queryset.
I am providing example,

```
    path = request.path
    if "autocomplete" in path:
        return super().get_queryset(request).filter()
    else:
        return super().get_queryset(request)
```

This will filter queryset if it is called from dropdown.
Thansk!